# MVC Data Model Validation DateTime with FoolProf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-modeling, foolproof-validation

I am validating two dates. I am using `FoolProf` to validate One date in `Greater than` the other like this...

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public System.DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[GreaterThan("StartDate")]
public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

The Problem I found is that it is validating other way round.

When I set a `StartDate` smaller than `EndDate`, the message it appears it

> StartDate can not be greatest than End Date...

And when I set a `EndDate` bigger than `StartDate`, no message appears.

What I am missing.?

Thanks

Comment: What are the dates your comparing and in what format.

Comment: the format is dd/mm/yyyy, and the dates is startdate="01/06/2017", and enddate es ="01/07/2017"... any other dates have the same problema. Thanks

Comment: foolproof adds rules to the `Query.validator` which uses dates in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` by default so its internally comparing an end date of 7th January with a start date of 6th January, not 1st July and 1st August as you may think